# Group by range of row numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 5000 rows, I want to split it into multiple dataframes based on the row value.

```py
object     result 
1200           1             
1201           0             
1202           1             
1203           0             
1204           0
```

The object row numbers are repeated for every 300 rows.
For rows, 1200- 1250 one dataframe, 1251-1300 another dataframe and so on.

Expected output for example:

Dataframe1:

```
object  result
1200     1
1201     0
1203     0
..
1250     1
```

Dataframe 2:

```
object  result
1251     1
1252     0
..
1301     1
```

Comment: Do You want to split to equal rowcount dataframes by every 50 rows starting from 1200 or by ranges of value of `object`  1200-1250, 1251-1300, etc. regardless how many rows will be in resulting dataframes?

Comment: Please, give a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the expected output, and what have you tried so far. It's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @ipj The row count is not equal. It is 50 for few and 100 for few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using division.

```
df['groupObject'] = df['object'].div(50).round().astype(int)
```

Now, you want to split the individual ints in the dataframe.
Here are all our groups:

```
groups = df['groupObject'].unique().values.tolist()

dfs = []
for group in groups:
   dfs.append(df[df['groupObject'] == group]
```

EDIT: Because the 50 is apparently not a constant, slice your dataframe like this:

```
df_temp = df[df['object'].astype(int) > 1250]]
```

and then proceed with the steps described above.

Comment: I used this df_temp = df[df['object'].astype(int) < 1250]  and gave limits df_temp = df[df['object'].astype(int) > 1250 & df['object'].astype(int) <1301]. It's working. Thank you for intuition. :)